# Memory leak on image component

Tags: wpf, image, listbox

I'm very new to wpf and am encountering the following problem.

I have a listbox that is filled with paths that point to a file stored on the system. 
I'm using the following code to accomplish this

```
    spriteImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images));
```

the problem is that when quickly browsing the lisbox the image update becomes sluggish until it takes about a second for the image to update.

Any suggestions as to how i can overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Do you keep images in memory?

Comment: ListBox uses a VirtualizingStackPanel, so it may be that when you scroll it that it needs some time to display the images

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the image element.
Image simpleImage = new Image();    
simpleImage.Width = 200;
simpleImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

// Create source.
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"/Images/1.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

bi.EndInit();
// Set the image source.
simpleImage.Source = bi;
```

This aslo could help you:

you might consider BitmapCacheOption.None. The image will be read directly from disk and not cached in memory.

Example how to use from memory stream:

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        stream.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage result = new BitmapImage();
        result.BeginInit();
        // According to MSDN, "The default OnDemand cache option retains access to the stream until the image is needed."
        // Force the bitmap to load right now so we can dispose the stream.
        result.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        result.StreamSource = stream;
        result.EndInit();
        result.Freeze();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a memory stream for the image. And the scrolling problem was resolved by adding the following line

```
    VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Jehof